# Javascript D3 position tooltip to chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I try to build a tooltip like it is explained here:
[D3 Tooltip Example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569)

But I want to have a div as a tooltip.
Now I have the problem to position the div to the chat line.
My code:

```js
var div = d3.select("#chart").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var path = svg.append("path") // Add the line path.
  .data(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line(data));

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .style("display", "none");

focus.append("text")
  .attr("x", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    focus.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(50)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);
  })
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);

function mousemove() {
  var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
    i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
    d0 = data[i - 1],
    d1 = data[i],
    d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

  //move focus around
  focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.equity) + ")");
  div.transition()
    .duration(50)
    .style("opacity", .9);
  div.html("<strong><table><tr><th>Datum:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>" + formatTime(d.date) + "</th></tr><tr><th>Equity:</th><th>" + Euro(d.equity) + "</th></tr></table></strong>")
  //     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  //       .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 1100) + "px");
  ;
}
```

The full example on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d60esLc8/4/)

Is it possible to position the div relatively to the svg line, where the mouse is?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the div position using `left` and `top` is best for HTML tooltips: https://jsfiddle.net/da3nx51L/

```
div.transition()
   .duration(50)
   .style('left', d3.event.clientX + "px")
   .style('top', d3.event.clientY + "px")
   .style('display', 'inline-block')
   .style("opacity", .9);
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the last two lines, and remove the `-1100` from the top

```
.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
.style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
```